# Are online Arduino simulators on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

For example, could I ask a question here about how to use Arduino features in http://circuits.io?

Comment: Isn't that interesting! I just discovered circuits.io a couple days ago.

Comment: Feel free to come and ask me a question [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47256/the-coyotes-den)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why not. As long as the question isn't about how to use the *simulator* itself (they should support their own product in that respect). Bear in mind that simulators don't always mimic real life hardware. Exact timing constraints, and marginal voltage levels might not be reproduced in the same way that real electronics would.